# Meaning of "Multiplying a function by some constant doesn't change it's asymptotic behavior"

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have understood this roughly as given a function f(n), if I multiply it with some constant "K" & f(n) = O(g(n)) :: f(n) <= c.g(n) for some n>=n1 then if I make f(n) as K*f(n) then there must be some other constant c1 by which we can multiply g(n) and cap (put a higher limit) to K*f(n).

What I am finding difficult to understand is the proper mathematical explanation given in the book:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just means that no matter what the constant time is the asymptotic behavior stays the same. example:

```
int fact;
for (fact=1;n>1;n--)  fact*=n;
```

is simple `O(n)` factorial with constant time `c` given by the time of single iteration of the loop and the multiplication `fact*=n`. Multiplying this by a constant means just that the `c` has changed for example:

```
int fact;
for (fact=1;n>1;n--)  
 if (bits(fact)+bits(n)<32)
  fact*=n;
```

Now the `c` is bigger because I added condition into the loop which takes some time. But the `O(n)` stays. What changes is the runtime. On the other hand if I change the code like this:

```
int fact;
for (fact=1;n>1;n--)  
 if (bits(fact)+bits(n)<32) fact*=n;
  else break;
```

Then I changed not only the constant time `c` but also the base asymptotic upper bound to `O(1)` because no matter how big `n` is this will stop when the result reached 32 bit limit which will be in constant time of steps for big enough `n` but this is not multiplying by a constant of coarse.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we have a function `f(n)` which we know to be in `O(g(n)`. This means, there exists an `n0` and `c`, such that:

```
f(n) <= c * g(n) \forall n >= n0
```

Now, if we analyze `K * f(n)`, it follows from the above definition that:

```
K * f(n) <= K * c * g(n) \forall n >= n0
```

We observe that `K * c` is again a constant. Hence, we can introduce another constant `c' = K * c` and write:

```
K * f(n) <= c' * g(n) \forall n >= n0
```

And this is exactly the big-O definition from above. Finally:

```
K * f(n) \in O(g(n))
```

It's just another constant.